# Garbage values after a certain amount of entries

Tags: c++

I have been banging my head against this tiny program I wrote just to test some matrix completion algorithms. I believe I may be overflowing the buffer but I am mostly curious as to why the entire buffer becomes corrupted.
Thank You

```
    MovieRating base[baseNum];
MovieRating test[NUM_RATINGS - baseNum];


//load the base data set
string line ="";
ifstream baseF("assets/u1.base");
ifstream testF("assets/u1.test");
if(baseF.fail()){
    cout << "Unable to open File. Program Terminating..."<<endl;
    return 1;
}

int i = 0;
getline(baseF, line);
while(baseF || i < sizeof(base)){
    base[i] = StringToRating(line);
    i++;
    getline(baseF,line);
}

cout << base[15000].mId << " " << base[15000].uId << " " << base[15000].rating << " " << base[15000].timestamp << endl;
baseF.close();
cout << base[15000].rating << endl;


//load testing dataset
if(testF.fail()){
    cout << "Unable to open File. Program Terminating..."<<endl;
    return 1;
}


i = 0;
getline(testF, line);
while(testF || i < sizeof(test)){
    test[i] = StringToRating(line);
    i++;
    getline(testF,line);
}
testF.close();
cout << base[15000].rating << endl;

GlobalMeanValue(base, test);
return 0;
```

NUM_RATINGS is 100,000 and baseNum is 80,000

The output from the first two couts is correct, the third is a garbage value after loading the last 20,000 movie ratings in.  Each MovieRating is 16 bytes.

Thanks again

Also I almost forgot this is on a 64-bit linux system.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is twofold, and on this line `while(baseF || i < sizeof(base)){`:

First, you mean to use `&&` instead of `||` so that once input is used up you're done.

Second, `sizeof(base)` is the total size of the array, NOT the number of elements, which is had by `sizeof(base) / sizeof(base[0])`

Comment: wow.. can't believe I missed that one.  Thank you so much just fixed the ors to ands and it worked perfectly.  As for the sizeof(base) is it correct for me to keep it how it was as all I am basically doing is making sure I don't write outside the bounds of the array? Thanks Again!

Comment: oh nevermind I understand what you are saying now, ran some tests to explain it to myself.  Thank You